# How to convert tail-recursive function to iterative

Tags: java, recursion, iteration, tail-recursion

How can you convert the following function so that it is iterative?

```
public static int recursion(int x, int y) {
    if(x <= 0) {
        return y + 13;
    } else if (x == 1) {
        return y;
    } else {
        return y * recursion(x - 2, y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Final code:

```
public static int iterative(int x, int y) {
    int result = 1;
    if(x <= 0) return y + 13;
    for(; x >= 0; x -= 2)
        result *= (x <= 0) ? y + 13 : y;
    return result;
}
```

---

The technique in your case is to turn the recursive call into a loop:

```
      while(true){

      }
```

let us look at the recursive call `y * recursion(x - 2, y);` there is a multiplication and only `x` changes, so we need to create a variable to keep track of the multiplication:

```
    int result = 1;
    while(true){
      //...
      result *= y;
      x = x - 2;
    }
```

We initialized to 1 because it is a multiplication. Let us look at the cases where the recursive call stops:

```
   if(x <= 0) {
        return y + 13;
    } else if (x == 1) {
        return y;
```

let us add them into loop:

```
    int result = 1;
    while(true){
        if(x <= 0) {
            result *= y + 13;
            break;
        }
       else if (x == 1){
            result *= y;
            break;
        }
       result *= y;
       x = x - 2;
    }
```

Now let us simplify the code, `result *= y;` shows two times, we can change the loop into:

```
   while(true){
        if(x <= 0) {
            result *= y + 13;
            break;
        }
        result *= y;
        if (x == 1){
            break;
        }
        x = x - 2;
    }
```

Since the value of `x` does not matter outside the loop we can simplify the loop even further:

```
do{
    if(x <= 0) {
        result *= y + 13;
    }
    else
        result *= y;
    x = x - 2;
}while(x >= 0);
```

Let us use the ternary operator:

```
    do{
        result *= (x <= 0) ? y + 13 : y;
        x = x - 2;
    }while(x >= 0);
```

Let us use a *for* loop instead :

```
public static int iterative(int x, int y) {
    int result = 1;
    for(; x >= 0; x -= 2)
        result *= (x <= 0) ? y + 13 : y;
    return result;
}
```

We need to cover the case when the method is called with x <= 0:

```
public static int iterative(int x, int y) {
    if(x <= 0) return y + 13;
    int result = 1;
    for(; x >= 0; x -= 2)
        result *= (x <= 0) ? y + 13 : y;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is a fantastic step-by-step explanation!

Comment: it was an accident! Sorry!

Comment: @h4ckerlinguist No issue it happens a lot in stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int recursion(int x, int y) {
  int result = 1;
  while(true) {
      if (x <= 0) {
          result *= (y + 13);
          break;
      } else if(x == 1) {
          result *= y;
          break;
      } else {
          result *= y;
          x -= 2; 
      }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int recursion(int x, int y) {
    for(x;x>=1;x-=2){
      y = y*y;
      if(x==1) break;
    }
   if(x<=0){
    return y*(y + 13);
   }else if(x==1){
    return y*y;
   }
 }
```

Comment: `x` is not a statement (in `for` statement), better `for( ;x>=1;x-=2)` || and why we need `if(x==1)break;` ? and missing a `return` after last `else if`

Comment: we need if(x==1)break; because if x =1 the condition of for loop is right so it will pass to other oteration  x =x-2 so we have now x = -1 that's why if x = 1 we will not pass to other iteration

Comment: wouldn't it be clearer to have that handled after the loop (and changing its condition) like is being done with next `if`? anyway , at least 2 compilation errors in above code

Answer (score 0):

Make lists where the needed variables are stored.

One possible way would be to have two loops:

1. In the first loop you simulate the recursive calls, and
2. in the second loop you then process the formula around those calls, namely `y*list[i]` (pseudocode).

**Tests:** Keep your recursive function, and write a test that calls both and compares results, to verify/validate your non-recursive algorithm.